# Stack overflow by presentModelViewController in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm still facing the problem when I launch my application in iPhone.

It shows the stack over flow by presentModelViewController because I'm using number of viewcontroller and calling the same viewcontroller from other viewcontroller but it gets terminated. Here I'm showing the code which I'm using in whole program to call other view controller

```
UV_AlarmAppDelegate *app7 = (UV_AlarmAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[self presentModalViewController:app7.frmComparisionChartLink animated:YES];
[app7 release];
```

Still I'm releasing the pointer but still my app gets terminated.

Comment: why in the world would you want to release the app delegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't release the app delegate. In short, unless you `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` an object you don't need to release it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation shows modalPresentation done like this;

```
UIViewController *uiViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil];
uiViewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:uiViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[navigationController release];
[uiViewController release];
```

Hopefully that helps.